# An attempt to define multilingual text macros, why doesn't it work?

Tags: macros, expl3

I am trying to create a command `\projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn` for creating multilingual text macros. Given a macro name `\<name>`, and a key-value configuration of texts (`english = ..., french = ...`), it should create sub-macros `\<name>_projlib_language_text_<languagename>`, and define the main macro `\<name>` to refer to them accordingly.

Below is my current attempt, which produces a few errors of `Undefined control sequence`.

Where does it go wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = key-value name configuration
  {
    \keyval_parse:nnn
      {}
      {
        \__projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text_do:nnn
          { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
      }
      { #2 }
    \tl_new:c  { #1 }
    \tl_set:cn { #1 }
      {
        \tl_use:c { #1 _projlib_language_text_ \languagename }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn { cn }

\cs_new:Nn \__projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text_do:nnn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = language name
% #3 = the text
  {
    \exp_args:Nx \tl_new:c  { #1 _projlib_language_text_ \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n { #2 } }
    \exp_args:Nx \tl_set:cn { #1 _projlib_language_text_ \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n { #2 } } { #3 }
  }


\cs_new:Nn \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n
  {
    \str_case_e:nn { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
      {
        {en}                    {english}
        {english}               {english}
        {fr}                    {french}
        {french}                {french}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn \test_text
  {
    EN = Some english text,
    FR = Quelques textes en français,
  }
% Should produce \test_text_projlib_language_text_english and \test_text_projlib_language_text_french, and define \test_text to call them accordingly

\selectlanguage{french}

% Should be >> Quelques textes en français
\test_text


\selectlanguage{english}

% Should be >> Some english text
\test_text

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

---

**ADD**: The accepted answer (alongside with his comments under the question) of David Carlisle kindly reminded the most dangerous syntax errors. The code above remains a few minor logical errors, for which the corrected version is posted below as an answer for your reference.

Comment: `\tl_new:N` or `\tl_new:c` just take the command name to be declared, not a `n` argument with the value, did you intende `\tl_const:cn` ? or `\tl_new` followed by `tl_set` ?

Comment: more generally if a comand is not documented in `textdoc interface3` then it is not defined by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I confused with `\cs_new:cn`. But even if I change them to `\tl_new` followed by `\tl_set`, it still have several errors.

Comment: If I make that change I get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.60 \seleclanguage` as you have not defined that. Is this a typo for selecTlanguage?

Comment: then `! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language 'language' yet.`   What did you expect `\selectlanguage{language}` to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, these are spell errors and the `\selectlanguage{language}` should be `\selectlanguage{english}`, I will edit the code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `expl3` error is that (as the error message says) there is no `tl_new:cn` you need to separate thedeclaration with `\tl_new` and setting with `\tl_set`, then the remaining errors were typos in the `\selectlanguage` use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = key-value name configuration
  {
    \keyval_parse:nnn
      {}
      {
        \__projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text_do:nnn
          { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
      }
      { #2 }
    \tl_set:cn { #1 }
      {
        \tl_use:c { #1 _projlib_language_text_ \languagename }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn { cn }

\cs_new:Nn \__projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text_do:nnn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = language name
% #3 = the text
  {
    \exp_args:Nx \tl_set:cn { #1 _projlib_language_text_ \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n { #2 } } { #3 }
  }


\cs_new:Nn \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n
  {
    \str_case_e:nn { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
      {
        {en}                    {english}
        {english}               {english}
        {fr}                    {french}
        {french}                {french}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N\test_text

\projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn \test_text
  {
    EN = Some english text,
    FR = Quelques textes en français,
  }
% Should produce \test_text_projlib_language_text_english and \test_text_projlib_language_text_french, and define \test_text to call them accordingly

\selectlanguage{french}

% Should be >> Quelques textes en français
\test_text


\selectlanguage{english}

% Should be >> Some english text
\test_text

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but there should exist some other mistakes, as the edited code still can't compile. I'm getting error messages `Undefined control sequence. \test_text`.

Comment: @Jinwen you do not get that error with the code as above. that is why  it has `\tl_new:N\test_text` The code posted runs without error.

Comment: Ah, the error is actually `Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex`, so there is no LaTeX error, but there are logical errors as `\test_text` shouldn't be empty.

Comment: @Jinwen ah.there is that!  I get no error but no output either, but I don't really know what the code's doing I just fixed the syntax errors, I'll let you debug for a bit, ask a new question if it's not clear

Answer (score 0):

There are several places in the original code that confuse `c` and `N` type argument. The correct version should be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = key-value name configuration
  {
    \keyval_parse:nnn
      {}
      {
        \__projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text_do:nnn
          { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
      }
      { #2 }
    \tl_set:Nn #1
      {
        \tl_use:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 _projlib_language_text_ \languagename }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn { cn }

\cs_new:Nn \__projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text_do:nnn
% #1 = command name
% #2 = language name
% #3 = the text
  {
    \exp_args:Nx \tl_set:cn { #1 _projlib_language_text_ \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n { #2 } } { #3 }
  }


\cs_new:Nn \projlib_language_str_to_languagename:n
  {
    \str_case_e:nn { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
      {
        {en}                    {english}
        {english}               {english}
        {fr}                    {french}
        {french}                {french}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N\test_text

\projlib_langauge_define_multilingual_text:Nn \test_text
  {
    EN = Some\ english\ text,
    FR = Quelques\ textes\ en\ français,
  }
% Should produce \test_text_projlib_language_text_english and \test_text_projlib_language_text_french, and define \test_text to call them accordingly

\selectlanguage{french}

% Should be >> Quelques textes en français
\test_text\\


\selectlanguage{english}

% Should be >> Some english text
\test_text\\

% \cs_meaning:N \test_text\\


% \test_text_projlib_language_text_english\\
% \test_text_projlib_language_text_french\\

--

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: it would probably be less confusing for future readers  if you accepted this one (I can manage without the 15 points:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand but surely your answer is more useful. I'm just posting the final version for future reference. Maybe it will be more helpful if I mention it under the question.